# Evaluate $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^4e^x}{(e^x-1)^2} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I am trying to find the value of the  integral below. Can anyone let me know how to evaluate this integral?
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^4e^x}{(e^x-1)^2} dx$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that the integral can be written as
$$\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{x^4e^{-x}}{(1-e^{-x})^2} dx = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k\int_0^{\infty}x^4 e^{-kx} dx = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k \cdot \dfrac{24}{k^5} = 24 \zeta(4) = \dfrac4{15} \pi^4$$

Comment: Is it possible have a solution with the tools of complex analysis?